# type error in Alloy

Tags: types, alloy

I have an Alloy specification to represent a subset of java programming language. Below we have some part of this model:

```
  abstract sig Type {}

  one sig void_ extends Type {}

  abstract sig PrimitiveType extends Type {}

  one sig Int_, Long_ extends PrimitiveType {}

  sig Method {
       id : one MethodId,
       param: lone Type,
       acc: lone Accessibility,
       return: one Type,
       b: one Body
    }{
     (return=void_) => ( 
        ( (b=ConstructorMethodInvocation) => (b.cmethodInvoked).return = void_) ||
        ( (b=MethodInvocation) => ((b.id_methodInvoked).return = void_) ) 
                       )
    }

    abstract sig Body {}

    sig MethodInvocation extends Body {
        id_methodInvoked : one Method,
        q: lone Qualifier
    }

    sig ConstructorMethodInvocation extends Body {
        id_Class : one Class,
        cmethodInvoked: one Method
    }{
        this.@cmethodInvoked.acc != private_
        this.@cmethodInvoked in ((this.@id_Class).*extend).methods
    }
```

In this code, there is a type error in Method signature, that is:

```
This cannot be a legal relational join where
left hand side is this . (this/Method <: b) .
(this/ConstructorMethodInvocation <: cmethodInvoked) (type =
{this/Method})
right hand side is this . (this/Method <: return) (type =
{this/Type})
```

And i am not understanding why.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "return" is implicitely scoped and thus represents the result of "this.return", i.e. "return" is already a "Type", not a relation from "Method" to "Type".

A possible solution is to avoid the implicit scoping by using a separate "fact" section and explicitly quantify over all "Methods":

```
fact {
  all m: Method | (m.return = void_ .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, wmeyer, but i do not understand why return is not a relation from "Method", why "return" is implicitely scoped? could you give me more details?

Comment: "return" is implicitly scoped because it is used inside of a signature fact. See Alloy 3.0 Reference Manual (can be found with Google). Quote: "Like any other fact, the signature fact is a constraint that always holds.  Unlike  other  facts,  however,  a  signature  fact  is  implicitly quantified over the signature set. Given the signature declaration `sig S {…} { F}` the signature fact F is interpreted as if one had written an explicit fact `fact{ allthis: S | F’}`

Comment: ok, thank you again for the clarification, wmeyer, but what i remain not understanding is: why return (as a valid relation of Method signature) can not be used in a signature fact?